# Question about »werden« and »anfangen«

Tags: translation, english-to-german, verb

Is it correct to write,

> In dieser Zeit wurde ich politisch bewusster.

as in "During this time I was becoming more politically aware"?

Also, what would be the German equivalent of saying "I started working\doing\becoming more ..."?

I feel that z.B.

> Ich fange an, politisch bewusster zu werden.

sounds kind of awkward, oder?

Comment: What do you mean with `politically aware` exactly? Caring for the best politics? Knowing, which parties are politically active? Being aware, that politics is a distinct aspect of society? If it's all of this, then `politisch bewusst` in all its broadness is appropriate. If it's only one of these, then you should use other, more specific translations.

Answer (score 2):

The sentence

> In dieser Zeit wurde ich politisch bewusster.

is correct.

There is also nothing inherently wrong with

> Ich fange an, politisch bewusster zu werden.

However, if you want to say "I started becoming more politically aware" the tense is wrong. You must use the preterite:

> Ich **fing** an, politisch bewusster zu werden.

The perfect ("Ich **habe angefangen**...") is also possible but in my opinion here the preterite should be preferred.

Answer (score 1):

Referring to the answer of @RHa

The translation

> Ich fing an, politisch bewusster zu werden.

can be written more polite:

> So begann ich, politisch bewusster zu werden.

For choosing the right translation, more context is needed.
Anyhow, `politisch bewusst` is a very broad statement. You could mean anything with that. You could clarify your statement further.

If you began to start working for a party or march at demonstrations you would say:

> So begann ich / Ich fing an, politisch aktiv zu werden.

If you started to favor left/right wing or developed your own opinion  for different political topics, than you would say:

> So begann ich / Ich fing an, mir eine politische Meinung zu bilden.

Answer (score 1):

*During this time I was becoming more politically aware.*

> In dieser Zeit begann ich mich für Politik zu interessieren.
>
> In dieser Zeit fand ich Interesse an Politik.

These phrases are idiomatic. The key to sound like a native German speaker is using as many nouns as possible and avoiding passive voice.

---

*I started working/doing/becoming more x.*

*I started working in a more focused manner.*

> Ich fing an, gewissenhafter zu arbeiten.

That doesn't sound awkward at all. You could also use a noun here:

> Ich fing mit gewissenhafterem Arbeiten an.

I would prefer the infinitive phrase in this case but the noun phrase sounds very German.